# Biopython: ImportError: No module named TreeConstruction

Tags: python, importerror, biopython

Someone knows why I get the following error?

```
>>> from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceCalculator, DistanceTreeConstructor

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction
ImportError: No module named TreeConstruction
```

And also:

```
>>> from Bio.Phylo.Consensus import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    from Bio.Phylo.Consensus import *
ImportError: No module named Consensus
```

Thanks to all for you time =)

Comment: Try `from Bio import Phylo` and then do `print dir(Phylo)` to see all the files that you can actually import.

Comment: Hi @Yax. This is the result: ['BaseTree', 'CDAO', 'NeXML', 'NeXMLIO', 'Newick', 'NewickIO', 'NexusIO', 'PhyloXML', 'PhyloXMLIO', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__docformat__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_cdao_owl', '_io', '_utils', 'convert', 'draw', 'draw_ascii', 'draw_graphviz', 'parse', 'read', 'to_networkx', 'write']

Comment: You can see that the two files you tried importing are not listed and that was why you were getting `importError`. You may have to try checking these subdirectories for the files you want to import or read the docs very well and attentively.

Comment: Read more about **Distance** functions here http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc189 and **Bio.Phylo** here http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Fixed!

The problem was that in the python IDLE, the version of biopython was 1.63, whereas the code

```
>>>from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceCalculator, DistanceTreeConstructor
```

works nice for version 1.65. So, the solution was delete the folder where biopython 1.63 was installed and download and later (re)install the biopython 1.65.